# Matebook x Pro endless boot loop

Tags: boot, bios, ubuntu-18.04

I have had a Matebook X Pro for about three weeks and I am running Ubuntu 18.10 on it. Recently I have restarted the computer following some installation guide and a problem occurred. The computer turns on, flashes the Huawei logo once, turns off, then two seconds later repeats this behaviour and this boot loop goes on forever. When I press <kbd>F12</kbd> to bring up the boot menu and select the SSD it says boot failed (even though the computer does see the SSD as an available bootable drive).

The computer doesn't boot up at all, not even until the Ubuntu loading screen.

I have handled the device carefully so it could not be a hardware failure due to shock or liquids or anything.

Could someone help me diagnose and solve the problem? I am happy to provide more edetail if needed.

Comment: What installation guide did you follow

Comment: @davidbaumann sadly I don't remember as I was playing around with installing many different apps and things. I did accidentally install something for an older version of Ubuntu  if that is of any help

Comment: I guess you messed up your system, so think about a fresh install.

Comment: @davidbaumann is this the only option I have?

Comment: @davidbaumann also do you have any ideas as to what kind of actions would mess up the system that bad? I doubt that downloading a program for Ubuntu 16 would be it.

Comment: If you can't even tell, what you did, I can't tell you either. Actually, make a fresh install and use VirtualBox for your experiments.

Comment: @davidbaumann thank you for your suggestion, I didn't even think of using virtual box!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I have solved the issue and I really hope that anyone who has it can benefit from my answer.

All I had to do was to go into BIOS (ctrl, alt, f2) then disable secure boot that is enabled by default. Then it all booted up and none of my data was lost. Thank you to everyone who tried to help